# How to remove html and php extensions from URL

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Hello I'm trying to hide html and php extension from my site URLs and here's my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/install -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(install) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /install/ [L,redirect=302]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\!$
RewriteRule ^(.*) stats.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\~s$
RewriteRule ^(.*) stats.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\~q$
RewriteRule ^(.*) generate_qr.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\~p$
RewriteRule ^(.*) preview_url.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.htm$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.gif$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.swf$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.xml$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.ico$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) url_redirector.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Any ideas how can i do that? I've tried a lot of answers that I found but it's not working out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Removing Extensions**

To remove the .php extension from a PHP file  you have to add the following code inside the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you want to remove the .html extension from a html file

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

To remove .html

```
  RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Updated

```
  RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: i put this RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] in my htaccess but not working i put it in the last line

Comment: i have tested its working fine for me if i have html.are you planning to hide all extension ?

Comment: @MounerMostafa.i have updated and its working fine.first yuo have to write rule for html and then php

Comment: see my update question i update htaccess file with ur code i put it in the last line but still not working

Comment: thanks man i just used that wrong now it's working . u just save my day many thanks

Comment: @MounerMostafa.Glade to here it helped you

Answer (score 3):

You can refactor your rules to reduce lot of redundancy and have 2 additional rules for hiding `.php` and `.html` extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/install -d
RewriteRule !^install/ /install/ [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(.+(?:!|\~s))$ stats.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+\~[pq])$ preview_url.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|js|css|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|ico|xml|txt|html?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.(php|html)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* url_redirector.php?url=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Just to let you know, what you got in other answer is actually not correct. It is not checking presence of `.php` or `.html` file before adding the extension. At present, it won't rewrite `example.com/about` to `example.com/about.php`